# flyTo() Leaflet - How can i fly on my map with onclick listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet

I'm stuck in my code.

I am working on interactive map and I need to fly on the coordinates with a problem. How do I know when is the problem active, well I have checked the status of the data and based on the status of object I have put them in different layers of Leaflet to show it on the map. Then I have put them in little table just below the map on my page where there is  elements with unique class, data-longitude and data-latitude variables that summaries how many problems we have, and where they are.

Now, this is where my problem is. I am new to JS and JQuery, so i need to know how can i access a  element attributes on click, so when i click on it it will do a function flyTo() and it will store a data-longitude + data-latitude attributes to that function.

Here is a little code with some ID's.

This is how I create  element in JS:

```
var newOption = host_name;
var uniqID = brojac;
div.innerHTML += '<td class="' + uniqID + '"value="' + newOption + '" data-longitude= "' + longitude + '" data-latitude="' + latitude + '">' + newOption + '</td>';
```

This is how I have created a table in HTML document:

```
<table id="tablic" style="width:100%">
    <caption>Aktivni problemi su na sljedećim DSLAM-ovima</caption>
    <tr id="red" itemprop='koordinate'></tr>
</table>
```

Sorry I can't put more info in it because its sensitive data so yea, hope you guys understand that.

One more thing, that "host_name", I'm getting that info from an JSON Object where I am creating markers for my map.

Hope I can get some good help with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JQuery:

Add a fix class to the td element:

`'<td class="tdclass ' + uniqID + '"value="' ....`

Then create a clicklistener on the class:

```
$('.tdclass').off('click').unbind('click').click(function(e){ //unbind and off is to remove the existing click events 
console.log(e);
console.log($(this).html());
console.log($(e).html());
    var lat = $(this).attr('data-latitude');
    var lng = $(this).attr('data-longitude');

    map.flyTo([lat,lng]);

});
```

Comment: Hey,

thank you for the response. I have tried that and it doesn't work. I don't get any error msgs in console, and the click isn't working. When I do inspect on one of the elements it looks like this.


`<td class="tdclass" value="****" data-longitude="****" data-latitude="****">**</td>`

Comment: add in the click function `console.log($(this));`. What do you get?

Comment: I get: 

`n.fn.init [document, context: document]`

Comment: try again with `console.log($(this).html());` and `console.log($(e).html());` pls

Comment: With `console.log($(this).html());`  i get "undefined".  With `console.log($(e).html());` get "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined"

Comment: Do you put the console in the click function? i updated my answer

Comment: Hey, sorry for not responding on time, didn't get into this since Friday. Well, no I didn't put it in the function. Now I have done that and I'm getting nothing in the output.

Comment: Pls try (also in the function) `console.log('test');` do you get this in the ouput? else your function is not called. Maybe you can share me your js file. f.e. over jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yea, I get nothing, so the function isn't called at all. Here you go, a JS file -> https://jsfiddle.net/kcm0dszb/. I removed some business related material, but still my JS file is so messy, I feel bad :(

Comment: You have forgott the dot in the JQuery use: `$('.tdclass')`

Comment: Sorry, I removed it to try something but forgot to put it back. It doesn't work with the dot either.

Comment: Look into your html have you `td` the attributes latitude and longitude? when I try it "raw" it works. https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/f3e6c0ps/

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the question. When I inspect an element of <td> I get: `<td class="tdclass" value="" data-longitude="13.600766" data-latitude="45.226259"></td>`. In HTML its like this: `<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table id="tablic" style="width:100%">
        <caption>Aktivni problemi su na sljedećim DSLAM-ovima</caption>
        <tr></tr>
    </table>
    </div>`

Comment: I have it now! You have to but the clicklistener in the Ajax success function. The Ajax function is async and so you added the listener to all tdclass elements before they exists

Comment: So if I got this right, I need to put a clicklistener in the function load_markers()? Or in Ajax success function?

Comment: in the ajax success function at the end

Comment: Yea, I got it, I tested it :). Well I'll be forever greatfull for this. Thank you :P